# How to fix no such column in sqlite in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am creating an android application that consists of a registration and forgot password field form using sqlite when i click on Reset password button inside the forgot password field I am getting an error called **android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: SECHINT (code 1):**
even i created a column in a table please help with this this is my activity:

```
        forgot_reset = (ButtonFlat)forgot_dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_button_Reset_forgot);
            forgot_reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    String stored_sec_hint = loginDataBaseAdapter.getAllTags(dialog_user_name_string);
                    if(confirm_sec_hint_forgot.equals(""))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(Login_Page.this, "Please enter your security hint to proceed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(stored_sec_hint==null)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(Login_Page.this, "Please Enter correct security hint to proceed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            show_pwd.setText(stored_pass);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            forgot_dialog.show();
    }

});
```

This is my db adapter class:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class LoginDataBaseAdapter 
{
        static final String DATABASE_NAME = "login.db";
        static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
        public static final int NAME_COLUMN = 1;
        // TODO: Create public field for each column in your table.
        // SQL Statement to create a new database.
        static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "+"LOGIN"+
                                     "( " +"ID"+" integer primary key autoincrement,"+"USERNAME  text UNIQUE,PASSWORD text,"+"SECHINT text); ";
        // Variable to hold the database instance
        public  SQLiteDatabase db;
        // Context of the application using the database.
        private final Context context;
        // Database open/upgrade helper
        private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;
        public  LoginDataBaseAdapter(Context _context) 
        {
            context = _context;
            dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }
        public  LoginDataBaseAdapter open() throws SQLException 
        {
            db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;
        }
        public void close() 
        {
            db.close();
        }

        public  SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance()
        {
            return db;
        }

        public void insertEntry(String dialog_user_name_string,String dialog_pasword_string,String dialog_seq_answer)
        {
           ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();

            newValues.put("USERNAME", dialog_user_name_string);
            newValues.put("PASSWORD",dialog_pasword_string);
            newValues.put("SECHINT", dialog_seq_answer);
            // Insert the row into your table
            db.insert("LOGIN", null, newValues);
            ///Toast.makeText(context, "Reminder Is Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        public int deleteEntry(String dialog_pasword_string)
        {
            //String id=String.valueOf(ID);
            String where="USERNAME=?";
            int numberOFEntriesDeleted= db.delete("LOGIN", where, new String[]{dialog_pasword_string}) ;
           // Toast.makeText(context, "Number fo Entry Deleted Successfully : "+numberOFEntriesDeleted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return numberOFEntriesDeleted;
        }   
        public String getSinlgeEntry(String dialog_user_name_string)
        {
            Cursor cursor=db.query("LOGIN", null, " USERNAME=?", new String[]{dialog_user_name_string}, null, null, null);
            if(cursor.getCount()<1) // UserName Not Exist
            {
                cursor.close();
                return "NOT EXIST";
            }
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String password= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PASSWORD"));
            cursor.close();
            return password;                
        }
        public void  updateEntry(String forgot_new_password_string)
        {
            // Define the updated row content.
            ContentValues updatedValues = new ContentValues();
            // Assign values for each row.
            //updatedValues.put("USERNAME", dialog_user_name_string);
            updatedValues.put("PASSWORD",forgot_new_password_string);


            String where="PASSWORD = ?";
            db.update("LOGIN",updatedValues, where, new String[]{forgot_new_password_string});             
        }

        public String getAllTags(String a) {

            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + "LOGIN" + " where SECHINT = '" +a + "'" , null);
            String str = null;
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
            str = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("PASSWORD"));
            } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
            return str;
            }


}
```

This is mylogcat:

```
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: SECHINT (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM LOGIN where SECHINT = 'null'
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:893)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:504)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1278)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at com.medequip.c1testpanel.LoginDataBaseAdapter.getAllTags(LoginDataBaseAdapter.java:91)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at com.medequip.c1testpanel.Login_Page$2$1.onClick(Login_Page.java:144)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFlat.onDraw(ButtonFlat.java:83)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14728)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13588)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13635)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3226)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13509)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13635)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3226)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13509)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13635)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3226)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13509)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13635)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3226)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13509)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13635)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3226)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13509)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13635)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.buildDisplayList(HardwareRenderer.java:1627)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1506)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2722)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2587)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2210)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1189)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6223)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
02-18 12:07:26.552: E/AndroidRuntime(11605):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: check `dialog_user_name_string=null`

Comment: `no such column: SECHINT`  probably issue is occurring due to table create query. missing space after `text,`

Comment: Sorry dude i cant understand you can you explain clearly @MD

Comment: I tried By placing space after text but it was no use dude@ρяσѕρєяK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of error comes only if you are trying to insert data in to a column which doesn't exist. There can be two cases:
1. The column that exist and the one in which you are inserting are different or there is some problem with the name.
2. The onCreate method of DBHelper class runs only the first time you instantiate the Database and there can be a case where the table creation was not don properly.

I would suggest to pull the database from you device or emulator and check it on SQLiteManager i.e a plugin for mozilla or you can check it on any other.

To pull the database from a real device please do the following:

```
adb shell "run-as package.name chmod 666 /data/data/package.name/databases/file"
adb pull /data/data/package.name/databases/file
```

By comparing the database you will definately find the problem.